# How to show only one panel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make sure that only the secret text is displayed on click, in the panel of which the "show" button was clicked. Now two panels are revealed at once ...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const onHandleVisible = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel1</h3>
        <button onClick={onHandleVisible}>Show</button>
        {!visible ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>

      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel2</h3>
        <button onClick={onHandleVisible}>Show</button>
        {!visible ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text 2</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-nash-nx4v6

Answer (score 1):

make 2 states

```
  const [visible1, setVisible1] = useState(true);
 const [visible2, setVisible2] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel1</h3>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible1(!visible1)}>Show</button>
        {!visible1 ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>

      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel2</h3>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible2(!visible2)}>Show</button>
        {!visible2 ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text 2</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it's also possible with single state.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const [ panel , setPanel ] = useState('Panel1');

  const onHandleVisible = (value) => {
    setPanel(value);
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel1</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible('Panel1')}>Show</button>
        {!visible && panel === 'Panel1' ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>

      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel2</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible('Panel2')}>Show</button>
        {!visible && panel === 'Panel2' ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text 2</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable for both use 2 variables to keep track which one is open.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-fire-0dng2

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [visiblePanel1, setVisiblePanel1] = useState(true);
  const [visiblePanel2, setVisiblePanel2] = useState(true);

  const onHandleVisible = panel => {
    if (panel === 1) {
      setVisiblePanel1(!visiblePanel1);
    } else if (panel === 2) {
      setVisiblePanel2(!visiblePanel2);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel1</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible(1)}>Show</button>
        {!visiblePanel1 ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>

      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel2</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible(2)}>Show</button>
        {!visiblePanel2 ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text 2</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit**
If there are multiple panels

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const [panelName, setPanelName] = useState();

  const onHandleVisible = panel => {
    setVisible(!visible);
    setPanelName(panel);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel1</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible("panel1")}>Show</button>
        {!visible && panelName === "panel1" ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>

      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel2</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible("panel2")}>Show</button>
        {!visible && panelName === "panel2" ? (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text 2</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also updated codesandbox.

Comment: And if there are a thousand such panels?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with 1 state, just make that state as visiblePanel and update name of panel in that state to show any particular panel

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-dust-6vrv7

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [visiblePanel, setVisiblePanel] = useState(null);

  const onHandleVisible = (panelName) => {
    if(panelName === visiblePanel) {
      setVisiblePanel(null);
    } else {
      setVisiblePanel(panelName);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel1</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible('panel1')}>Show</button>
        {visiblePanel === 'panel1' && (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text</h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="panel">
        <h3>Panel2</h3>
        <button onClick={() => onHandleVisible('panel2')}>Show</button>
        {visiblePanel === 'panel2' && (
          <div>
            <h1>I am secret text 2</h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```